# Solidity Compiler and EVM relationship

Tags: compiler

When I compile the below code in 0.6.6 it doesn't compile (requires public) but in 0.7.3 it does compile.

If I make the below code compilable (adding public) in 0.6.6 I can successfully deploy on Rinkeby.  If I compile the below code in 0.7.3 I can successfully deploy on Rinkeby.  This would suggest that there are no changes to Rinkeby EVM, only the way compiler versions enforce Bytecode arrangement has changed?

Does this imply I could use 0.6.6 compiler standards for many more years down the road and my code won't break?  The numerous compiler iterations is a new experience for me and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

Thank you

```
contract A { constructor () payable {} }
```

Comment: Check this:https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9088/will-existing-smart-contracts-stop-working-if-solidity-language-changes

Comment: Thank you for this link Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Solidity version changes are often

- Syntactical changes (make the language safer)
- ABI changes (see Ethereum smart contract [ABI v2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64566/620)

EVM changes add new instructions, like ones for `revert(string)` and `catch` and then these are adopted into Solidity as language constructs, but these changes are more rare.